# N-dimensional operators

Tags: notation, binary-operations

My view of standard mathematical operations (`+ - * /`) is that they are spatially unidimensional in the sense that **every mathematical calculation can be expressed in a single line** (using proper parenthesis). Or more precisely, an operator **always takes two elements**, one at its "left" and one at its "right".

For example,

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{5}+19}{x+1} - 9$$

is equivalent to

$$(3/5+19)/(x+1)-9$$

where each operator has a component at each side, all in a uni-dimensional space (i.e. a line).

**Is there a mathematical field where operators are "non-unidimensional"?**

For example, a **2D operator** could take one element at each side, and also one element above:

$$ 5 \overset{7}{\lozenge} 8 = 21 $$

Which could be combined so that:

$$ 5 \overset{ 1 \overset{8}{\lozenge} 5 }{\lozenge} 8 = 96 $$

This operator cannot be reduced to a 1 dimension (unless you re-specify it as a function on 1D operators).

A **3D operator** could take elements at each side, above, and in front (cannot shown here).

Comment: Please feel free to edit the tags of this question accordingly.

Comment: A related topic is [Universal Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra), and another related topic is [Tensor Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator).

Comment: Does [$a\uparrow^n b$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) count?

Comment: The way you've framed this seems like a matter of notation, rather than the characteristics of operators themselves.  The $\lozenge$ operator you describe could just as easily be written $\lozenge(5,7,8) = 21, \lozenge(5,\lozenge(1,8,5),8) = 96$.